# Trivial question about limit of an indicator function

Tags: limits, characteristic-functions

I've seen in some places where authors write, say, $1_{[0,\infty)}$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}1_{[0,n)}$, when dealing with some summation or integration. Would it have made any difference if $[0,n)$ were replaced by $[0,n]$? I am just worrying, that $1_{[0,n]}$ might tend to $1_{[0,\infty]}$ instead of $1_{[0,\infty)}$.

Comment: What does $[0,\infty]$ mean?

Comment: @user658409 $[0,\infty)\cup \{\infty\}$. I know it seems a stupid question, but I just want to know it would have made any difference stated in my question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1_{[0,n]}$ also tends to $1_{[0,\infty)}$ at every point of $\mathbb R$. Proof: If $x < 0$ then $1_{[0,n]}(x)=0=1_{[0,\infty)}$ for all $n$. If $x \geq 0$ then $1_{[0,n]}(x)=1=1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ whenever $n \geq x$.  Hence the limit of $1_{[0,n]}(x)$ is equal to $1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate why this holds?

Comment: @UnknownW I have added a proof.